# Connection pool for selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Running selenium tests in python and chrome. Between each test, it logs that its creating a new http connection.

Is it possible to create a connection pool so that a new one isn't created for each test?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the low details provided on your question, and that you're mentioning that this happens only between tests, leads me to think that you have something in your setUp or tearDown methods.
Check what gets executed there and see whether that is the source of your problem.